# Non-existent page returns code 200

Tags: 404-error

I have a page like mysite.com/contacts/
If I enter non-existent urls like:

```
mysite.com/contacts--/
mysite.com/contacts%20/
```

i get status 200 and the page opens mysite.com/contacts/
although if I enter:

```
mysite.com/contacts1/
```

As expected, I am getting a 404 error.

How can I implement error handling at the CMS level so that non-existent pages return a page with a 404 error template? There may be some plugin that implements URL management?

Comment: Yes, this is WordPress trying to be helpful by redirecting bad URLs to a close match. Do you want to turn that off? I can't remember what it's called in the code though to search for it right now.

Comment: Rup, yes i want to turn it off. My SEO specialist says that it has a bad effect on website promotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**That's not what's happening**, when you visit `/contacts--/` it doesn't return a 200 code, but instead it returns a `301` redirect code. The browser then follows this redirect and heads to `/contact` and it's `/contact` that returns `200` code.

This is because `/contact` is the canonical URL of that page, and WordPress redirects to canonical pages out of the box for improved SEO. It should also be adding a meta tag to the header containing the canonical URL to avoid duplicate content penalties.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't notice that I was getting rel="canonical" on the returned page.

Comment: There's a filter somewhere that turns this off, but I wouldn't recommend it

Answer (score 0):

If you need to prevent WordPress from guessing URLs, you can add the following code to function.php

```
function remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink( $redirect_url ) {
  if ( is_404() ) {
    return false;
  } //end if
  return $redirect_url;
} //end remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink()
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'remove_redirect_guess_404_permalink' );
```

[Link to article](https://neliosoftware.com/blog/devtips-how-to-stop-wordpress-from-guessing-urls/?nab=0)

Comment: I don't think that was the problem here though? (although I admit I thought it was to start with)